# Spring MockRestServiceServer handling multiple requests to the same URI (auto-discovery)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mocking, integration-testing

Let's say I am writing Spring integration tests for a REST service A. This service in turn hits another REST service B and gets a list of URIs to hit on REST service C. It is kind of auto-discovery pattern. I want to mock B and C responses using MockRestServiceServer.
Now the response from B is a list of URIs, they are all very similar, and for the sake of the example lets say my response from B is like so:

```
{
    uris: ["/stuff/1.json", "/stuff/2.json", "/stuff/39.json", "/stuff/47.json"]
}
```

Simply service A will append each of them onto base URL for service C and make those requests.
Mocking B is easy since it is only 1 request.
Mocking C is a hassle as I would have to mock every single URI to appropriate mock response. I want to automate it!
So first I write my own matcher to match not a full URL, but part of it:

```
public class RequestContainsUriMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    private final String uri;

    public RequestContainsUriMatcher(String uri){
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    public void match(ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest) throws IOException, AssertionError {
        assertTrue(clientHttpRequest.getURI().contains(uri));
    }
}
```

This works fine as now I can do this:

```
public RequestMatcher requestContainsUri(String uri) {
    return new RequestContainsUriMatcher(uri);
}

MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate)
            .expect(requestContainsUri("/stuff"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(/* I will get to response creator */);
```

Now all I need is a response creator that knows the full request URL and where the mock data sits (I will have it as json files in test resources folder):

```
public class AutoDiscoveryCannedDataResponseCreator implements ResponseCreator {
    private final Function<String, String> cannedDataBuilder;

    public AutoDiscoveryCannedDataResponseCreator(Function<String, String> cannedDataBuilder) {
        this.cannedDataBuilder = cannedDataBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse createResponse(ClientHttpRequest clientHttpRequest) throws IOException {
        return withSuccess(cannedDataBuilder.apply(requestUri), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .createResponse(clientHttpRequest);
    }
}
```

Now stuff is easy, I have to write a builder that takes request URI as a string and returns mock data, as a String! Brilliant!

```
public ResponseCreator withAutoDetectedCannedData() {
    Function<String, String> cannedDataBuilder = new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String requestUri) {
            //logic to get the canned data based on URI
            return cannedData;
        }
    };

    return new AutoDiscoveryCannedDataResponseCreator(cannedDataBuilder);
}

MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate)
            .expect(requestContainsUri("/stuff"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withAutoDetectedCannedData());
```

It works fine! .... For the first request.
After the first request (/stuff/1.json) my MockRestServiceServer responds with message "Assertion error: no further requests expected".
Basically, I can make as many requests to that MockRestServiceServer as there were .expect() calls on it. And since I had only 1 of them, only first request will go through.
Is there a way around it? I really don't want to mock service C 10 or 20 times...

Comment: Thanks for the RequestContainsUriMatcher implementation

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you look at the MockRestServiceServer class, it supports two 'expect()' methods. The first defaults to 'ExpectedCount.once()' but the second method allows you change this value

```
public ResponseActions expect(RequestMatcher matcher) {
    return this.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), matcher);
}

public ResponseActions expect(ExpectedCount count, RequestMatcher matcher) {
    return this.expectationManager.expectRequest(count, matcher);
}
```

I found this ticket [MockRestServiceServer should allow for an expectation to occur multiple times](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11365) which outlines some options for second method.

In your case I think adding static import and using the manyTimes() method is neater code than the for loop

```
MockRestServiceServer
            .expect(manyTimes(), requestContainsUri("/stuff"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
```

Other options are

```
once();
manyTimes();
times(5);
min(2);
max(8);
between(3,6);
```

Comment: Implemented in Spring 4.3

Comment: This is now the correct answer and should be selected as such.

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: See answer from @emeraldjava which shows the correct solution for Spring 4.3+ users.

Unfortunately there isn't any *nice* mechanism to expect multiple calls. You either do it manually or use loops, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           
        mockRestServiceServer
                .expect(requestContainsUri("/stuff"))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withAutoDetectedCannedData());
}
```

Be aware that the requests must be called without any interruptions, e.g. there cannot be another REST call that doesn't match the "/stuff" URI.

Comment: Once an expectation is tested you cannot add additional expectations.  

`Can't add more expected requests with test already underway`

Answer (score 0):

For me the situation was a little different. In my test class I had 2 helper methods which handled the stub request. Since one of these methods was located after the other one, it I received the following error: **`Cannot add more expectations after actual requests are made.`**

What solved the error for me, was creating a new mockRestServiceServer in each of the methods:

E.g, what gave me an error was this:

```java
public void testStubRequestMethodOne(String expectedURL){

        mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo(basePath + expectedURL))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        api.performPost(parameter1, parameter2)
        
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();

        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
}

// SERIES OF UNIT TESTS //

public void testStubRequestMethodTwo(String expectedURL, String extraURLPart){

        mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo(basePath + expectedURL + extraURLPart))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        api.performPost(parameter1, parameter2)
        
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();

        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
}
```

**Basically, the expectations were declared 2 times in the same test class.**

What solved it was changing those helper methods to:

```java
public void testStubRequestMethodOne(String expectedURL){
        mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build(); /*<-- this is new*/

        mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo(basePath + expectedURL))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        api.performPost(parameter1, parameter2)
        
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();

        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
}

// SERIES OF UNIT TESTS //

public void testStubRequestMethodTwo(String expectedURL, String extraURLPart){
        mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build(); /*<-- this is new*/

        mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo(basePath + expectedURL + extraURLPart))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        api.performPost(parameter1, parameter2)
        
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();

        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
}
```